# How to parse invalid JSON, delimited by a newline

Tags: python, json, mongodb

### Mongodb log messages are JSON format, they reside in a file called mongod.log, each log message is separated by a newline \n

I am trying to:

- Capture each line(log message) of valid JSON
- Turn JSON into python dictionary

The error I keep getting is

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1
```

I know this is being thrown because the entire log file is not valid JSON, only individual log messages.

### How do I iterate through individually?

At first I thought to make my own **iter**, **next** to grab each line and move once valid json(log message) was dealt with.
I am now seeing there is a way to use
[json.Decoder](https://abhinavg.net/posts/parse-ndjson/)  to parse Newline Delimited JSON

```
import json

file_path = mongod.log

with open(file_path, 'r') as file
    data = json.load(file)
    print(data)
```

### mongod.log

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-09T15:50:43.475-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-10T10:33:51.002-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23377,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Received signal","attr":{"signal":15,"error":"Terminated"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T21:38:59.486-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20714,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Failed to refresh session cache, will try again at the next refresh interval","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
```

Comment: please add a sample of that `mongod.log` file to your question (as text!).

Comment: I think you are talking about jsonl files? If yes, try doing `df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf="mongod.log", lines=True)`

Comment: That's called JSONL. There are plenty of libraries that do support it.

Answer (score 1):

You can import this file the way you tried like this:

```py
import json
file_path = 'mongod.log'
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(line) for line in f])
print(df)
```

...which has output:

```
                                            t  s        c     id                         ctx                                                msg                                               attr
0  {'$date': '2021-03-09T15:50:43.475-06:00'}  I  CONTROL  20712     LogicalSessionCacheReap  Sessions collection is not set up; waiting unt...  {'error': 'NamespaceNotFound: config.system.se...
1  {'$date': '2021-03-10T10:33:51.002-06:00'}  I  CONTROL  23377               SignalHandler                                    Received signal              {'signal': 15, 'error': 'Terminated'}
2  {'$date': '2021-04-02T21:38:59.486-05:00'}  I  CONTROL  20714  LogicalSessionCacheRefresh  Failed to refresh session cache, will try agai...  {'error': 'NotYetInitialized: Replication has ...
```

or with `pd.read_json` as in the comments suggested:

```py
file_path = 'mongod.log'
df = pd.read_json(file_path, lines=True)
print(df)

#same df as in the first way
```

For the two columns with dicts in each row you could continue like this:

```py
dict_cols = ['t', 'attr']
res = (pd.concat([df,
                 *(pd.json_normalize(df.pop(col)) for col in dict_cols)
                 ],axis=1)
      )
print(res)
```

...with output:

```
   s        c     id                         ctx                                                msg                          $date                                              error  signal
0  I  CONTROL  20712     LogicalSessionCacheReap  Sessions collection is not set up; waiting unt...  2021-03-09T15:50:43.475-06:00  NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does...     NaN
1  I  CONTROL  23377               SignalHandler                                    Received signal  2021-03-10T10:33:51.002-06:00                                         Terminated    15.0
2  I  CONTROL  20714  LogicalSessionCacheRefresh  Failed to refresh session cache, will try agai...  2021-04-02T21:38:59.486-05:00  NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet bee...     NaN
```